# Bootstrap 3 Modal Shown Sometimes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, show-hide

I have strange behaviour with the modal dialog in Bootstrap 3.

I load data via AJAX and show the data within the dialog. Everythings seems to be ok. The dialog will be shown. I click on the link for showing the dialog. It works, but sometimes (perhaps after 5 times or after 20 times clicking the link) it doesn´t. The background becomes dark - but the modal does not appear. I checked it with firebug and the data came from the server, but the dialog will not show.

Do anyone have an idea what it could be?

Comment: thsi will be in firefox und chrome on win 7

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior on Safari.

Comment: I have reproduced this bug without AJAX, using the bootstrap example page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals -- Just click the "Launch demo modal button 10 or so times and you will see the bug. I logged this issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14254

Comment: The latest version of this bug appears to be limited to Safari.

Comment: Anyone have fixes for this?

Comment: Safari 7.1 fixes the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a shot in the dark, but it's possible that the modal is not being reset correctly once it closes. When the modal closes, it still retains the content, and the data about it's state. This will clean out the data, and also remove the modal's content.

You could try this:

```
$('#my-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function( {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal').children().remove();
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. There appears to be a bug in Bootstrap 3.2.0.

Comment: It was actually a bug in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

The bug has been fixed in Safari 7.1.